# What is the SQL Server equivalent for Oracle's systimestamp?

Tags: sql-server, oracle

Anyone have an idea on how to find the SQL Server equivalent for Oracle's systimestamp? SYSDATETIMEOFFSET() is the closest match I could find...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know SYSDATETIMEOFFSET() is the equivalent. Did you find any difference between both ?

Comment: There is a small difference, Oracles systimestamp displays the month as a 3 letter abbreviation ie Aug and SQL Server displays it as a number ie 08. But I realized that SYSDATETIMEOFFSET() will work in this case regardless. Thanks for the help.

Comment: This is the formatting - you can use convert() to change the formatting

Answer (score 1):

The equivalent SQL Server data type would be DateTimeOffset.

The method to generate the current date time with offset would be as you indicate, SysDateTimeOffset().